# How to fix multiple intent.getStringExtra() returns null value ? ( Kotlin )

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, kotlin

I'm trying to get Two strings from two different classes but it's return null for the first intent ( mySPECIALITY ) and the second does not change it's correct.

> All the textView returns : null sPECIALITYtxt

```
    val mySPECIALITY = intent.getStringExtra("LEVEL+YEAR+SEMSTER")
    val sPECIALITY=intent.getStringExtra("SpecialityNAME")
    textViewSPECIALITY.text= "$mySPECIALITY $sPECIALITY"
```

The first intent i set using this code :

```
val intent = Intent(this,CalculatingPage::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("LEVEL+YEAR+SEMSTER",calledSemYear)
                startActivity(intent)
```

The second intent i set using this code :

```
        val intent = Intent(mContext, CalculatingPage::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("SpecialityNAME", mData[position].getspecialityFullName())
        mContext.startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: First read this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html and then explain in more details the problem.

Comment: my problem is that the first intent returns null that's all

Comment: Post the code from the activity class that sets these extras.

Comment: @forpas please check it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use 2 intents to open 1 activity. 
Create 1 intent and put 2 extra values in it:

```
val intent = Intent(this,CalculatingPage::class.java)
intent.putExtra("LEVEL+YEAR+SEMSTER", calledSemYear)
intent.putExtra("SpecialityNAME", mData[position].getspecialityFullName())
startActivity(intent)
```